# Lat Long is projected incorrectly?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, coordinate-system

I am storing OS Open Local data, as downloaded here: https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html (top result).

I've imported the `.shp` files.

Running the `.prj` through here: http://prj2epsg.org/search produces:

```
    PROJCS["British_National_Grid",GEOGCS["GCS_OSGB_1936",DATUM["D_OSGB_1936",
SPHEROID["Airy_1830",6377563.396,299.3249646]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["False_Easting",400000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",-100000.0],
PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-2.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996012717],
PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",49.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0],AUTHORITY["EPSG",27700]]
```

So in my postgis db I run:

```
SELECT srid FROM spatial_ref_sys WHERE srtext LIKE '%British_National_Grid%';
```

Which produces two results:
27700 and 7405

By inspection the former corresponds exactly to my `.prj`

Verifiying my SRID on my column:

```
SELECT Find_SRID('', 'buildings', 'geometry');

 find_srid 
-----------
         0
(1 row)
```

Fine, so casting the column to `27700` should do the trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM buildings AS b
WHERE ST_DWithin(ST_SetSRID(b.geometry, 27700),
ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-0.1047, 51.5236), 4326),27700),
500);
```

(Note that (51.5246, -0.1047) is downtown London)

This query produces no results. interestingly, increasing the radius to 15000, produces 8748 results. Casting an arbitrary one to 4326 and using `ST_AsGeoJSON` to produce a readable result gives a location in the suburbs (northwest) of London which suggests that my coordinates are somewhat off...

EDIT: Flipping the coordinates to correspond to more traditional coordinate systems also generates no results (more or less at any radius, I've gone up to 500000):

```
SELECT *
FROM buildings AS b
WHERE ST_DWithin(ST_SetSRID(b.geometry, 27700),
ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(51.5236, -0.1047), 4326),27700),
500000);
```

How can I figure out where and/or how things are going wrong? And how can then fix this?

Comment: Question edited to include result of flipping coordinate system to be correct

Comment: you need to set the srid of your buildings layer to 27700 not 0

Comment: isn't that being done by the `ST_SetSRID(b.geometry, 27700)`?

Comment: {51.5246, -0.1047} is in the middle of the Atlantic Ocean, near the equator.

Comment: so which order are the coordinates supposed to be in then? There are two directly conflicting comments on this question...

Comment: Coordinates are entered in X,Y order, so longitude,latitude is proper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may not have imported your shapefile correctly as this works for me.

First create the table (as shp2psql had an issue with the add geom column):

```
CREATE TABLE "ian"."buildings" (gid serial,
"id" varchar(38),
"featcode" int4);
ALTER TABLE "ian"."buildings" ADD PRIMARY KEY (gid);
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('ian','buildings','geom','27700','MULTIPOLYGON',2,true);
```

then import the shapefile:

```
shp2pgsql -s 27700 -I -a Building.shp ian.buildings | psql -f -
```

Then the query

```
SELECT *
FROM buildings AS b
WHERE ST_DWithin(ST_SetSRID(b.geom, 27700),
ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-0.1047,51.5236), 4326),27700),
5000);
```

returns 7180 buildings.

Note I was wrong in my assumption that PostGIS would do the right thing with lat/lon v. lon/lat as can be seen with the following test.

```
SELECT ST_ASTEXT(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-0.1047,51.5236), 4326),27700));
```